# How can I send a single Downkey key when my user taps the numpad Enter key?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, key

This is purely for a usability request my clients have asked me.

They work with a datagridview typing in grades for students. So they pretty much go into zombie mode and start tapping in numbers, and they've told me that it would be easier if they could tap the numpad enter key to have the next vertical select focused.

Here's what I've tried to use:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. Sometimes it seems to fire that key many times, causing the focus to scroll 2 or 3 or 4 cells downwards and really shaking up the users focus.

How can I make this work and make my clients happy?

Comment: have you considered an array of text fields?

Comment: try adding an e.handled=true after your SendKeys.Send

Comment: Is the program they are using have source you have access to?  If so, why not just accept the enter key and use it - otherwise I think you need an IntPtr handle to their window and to send specifically to that window.

Comment: @Chuck: I'm not sure what you mean, pressing the enter key while in a datagridview cell doesn't scroll vertically downwards how I want it to.

Comment: Can't you just take the next row, Select it and then do EnsureVisible() on the cell?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void datagridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        bindingsource.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  - I have tested it and it works.

```
private void datagridView12_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
     {
         int col = dataGridView12.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
         int row = dataGridView12.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
         if (row != dataGridView12.NewRowIndex)
         {
             if (col == (dataGridView12.Columns.Count - 1))
             {
                 col = -1;
                 row++;
             }

             dataGridView12.CurrentCell = dataGridView12[col, row + 1];
         }

         e.Handled = true;
         base.OnKeyDown(e);
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean that is set to true on keyDown and set to false on keyUp.

Only run your sendKeys.Send when the boolean is true. That should ensure that the event is only fired once for every key press.

That's often how I've seen it done in other languages, I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the DataGridView (whether in edit mode or not) it goes one cell down by default (in .NET framework 3.5 and 4.0).

Isn't it the functionality you needed in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

Can you not set the focus on the next textbox when the user presses enter?
You can use the TextBox.Focus() method to move the next textbox.

Comment: This is for a datagridview, nothing to do with a textbox.